# bpopup plugin opnes popup only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event, bpopup

I'm using the jquery bpopup plugin.
I'd like to use the same script for all buttons/popups on a page.
Unfortunately each button click only works once after page load.
I would be very thankful for you help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://dinbror.dk/downloads/jquery.bpopup-0.7.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.button').live('click', function(e) { 

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $(this).find('.popup').bPopup({

            });

        });

    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Button 1 -->
        <div class="button">Button1
        <div class="popup" style="background-color:#fff; width:400px; height:400px; display:none">
            PopUp Content1
            </div>
        </div>

                <!-- Button 2 -->
        <div class="button">Button2
            <div class="popup" style="background-color:#fff; width:400px; height:400px; display:none">
            PopUp Content2
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply click on document along with filter of your .button class. It is recommended to use `on` instead of `Live` is deprecated.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nUdnc/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
        $(this).find('.popup').bPopup({

        });            
    });

});​
```

**Edit as per  discussion in comments about origninal post.**

The jquery `bpopup` library is used for creating popup. The library makes changes in dom and move the popup div from its place which causes the next time popup failure. This could be seen [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nUdnc/12/)

I have changed the html and javascript to handle the dom change made by `bpopup`. This could be seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nUdnc/14/)**. These changes are made to make it run and could be adjusted according to requirements.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nUdnc/14/)**

**Updated HTML**

```
    <!-- Button 1 -->
    <div id="button1" class="button">Button1</div>
       <div class="popup" style="background-color:#fff; width:400px; height:400px; display:non">
        PopUp Content1
        </div>
    <!-- Button 2 -->
    <div id="button2" class="button">Button2</div>
    <div  class="popup" style="background-color:#fff; width:400px; height:400px; display:none;">
        PopUp Content2
    </div>
```

​
**Updated Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).next('.popup').length == 1) {
            $(this).next('.popup').attr('attachedbutton', $(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).next('.popup').bPopup({
            });
        }
        else {
                $('body').parent().find("'.popup[attachedbutton=" + this.id + "]'").bPopup({
                 });
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Put some alert in click or debug the click event to assure if it is fired. Also updated my code try this too.

Comment: there's a typo (`ducument` in place of `document`). This can be the reason, its not working

Comment: sorry, but the script doesn't execute. I added an alert and it seems it's not fired....

Comment: i used my inital script again and added an alert. the script is fired every time i click the button, but for some reason the popup only appears once... $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('.button').on('click', function(e) { 
               // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
               e.preventDefault();
      
      // Alert
      alert('clicked')
               
      // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
               $(this).find('.popup').bPopup({

            });

        });

    });

Comment: There was typing mistake in my code, I typed ducument instead of document make sure you have latest code

Comment: Please check it over there, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/nUdnc/ and take updated answer

Comment: thanks, i checked and added the bpopup plugin to the script... when clicking the same button more than once the popup doesn't appear anymore  http://jsfiddle.net/nUdnc/1/

Comment: I have updated my answer, the cause of problem was the bpopup js library, I have made some changes to make it run. You can adjust as per your requirements.